# (PL)SQL: Updating fields with existing fields from the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Ok, so lets pretend I have a table like this:

```
tbl1:

+----+---------+------+--------+-------+--------+-----
| PK | EntrySK | name | deptId | aclID | BankID | ...
+----+---------+------+--------+-------+--------+-----
|  1 |      -1 | null |     -1 |    -1 |    ... |
|  2 |     123 | aaa  |    124 |    32 |    ... |
|  5 |     124 | bbb  |    123 |   156 |    ... |
|  6 |     125 | ccc  |    126 |    32 |    ... |
|  7 |     126 | ddd  |    123 |   453 |    ... |
+----+---------+------+--------+-------+--------+-----
```

The first row contains all the defaults values for this table.

I need to apply all those default values to some fields that are considered secret (bank data, addresses...), if the deptID is 123 or 126 or the aclID is 32 or 453.

My idea was to do it like this:

```
update tbl1
set tbl1.name = null
/* fields here */
where tbl1.PKin (
               select tbl1.PK from tbl1 where tbl1.DeptID in (123,126)
                  union
               select tbl1.PK from tbl1 where where tbl1.aclID in (32,453)
              )
```

But now one would still need to add all fields manually.

Does someone know how to do this (preferably with pure SQL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two components to this.  One is using a `where` clause to get the right rows to update.  the other is setting the columns.

For the latter, Oracle lets you set multiple columns at the same time using a subquery:

```
update tbl1
    set (name, bankid, . . .) =
         (select name, bankid, . . .
          from tbl1
          where entrySK = -1
         )
    where deptID in (123, 126) or aclID in (32, 453);
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I had a way more complicated method in mind when approaching this problem, when it actually can be solved this easily.